# Connecting to the database via the internet

Tags: c#

I've created a 3 tier windows forms application. It works 
fine on a LAN. But the problem that i'm facing right now
is that i want the client application to be able to connect
to the server database via the internet. Why via the internet?  Because there is a chance that the server pc and
the client pc might become 250km apart.

The other thing is that, i want this connection to be a secured one. This means only specific computers are allowed to connect to this database.

Is there a way to accomplish this? 
Is there an Ebook that i can read on, that will help me 
accomplish this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes - move the middle tier to some place where it does not need to talk to DB via internet, and make your client "talk" to that middle tier.

Comment: isn't there an option for using a VPN?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : how do i make my client talk to the middle tier? Isn't that gonnabe the same thing(connection via internet)?

Comment: @jorne : I'm not really familiar with the VPN. So i'm not sure if it's gonna work or not. Tha'ts why i'm asking you guys.

Comment: check the Wikipedia of VPN and see of it is something you'r looking for
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

Comment: @jorne thanks. Oh the reason why i want to do something like this, is because i'm having 2 guys that got laptop each, and this laptops got a c# application that gets the data from the user and save that data to the database. But my challenge is that this guys they live in different provinces, which is about 250km apart. So that's why i decided to come up with an idea to create a centralized server that can be accessed via the internet.

Comment: @Sam1 : Okay ill check wcf services. Thanks.

Comment: @chosenOneThabs Yes, you would connect to your middle tier using internet, but you would have a lot more options as to how you can do it, and a lot more control over what gets transferred to the client. In general, using communication with DB your network protocol is a costly mistake, because it is virtually impossible to make that communication fast. I made this mistake a couple of times in the past (once in Java and once in .NET). Then learned my lesson, and moved on. You do not have to repeat my mistake, unless you want to :)

Comment: You need to go with the advice provide by @dasblinkenlight. This is how n-tier distributed systems are handled. The middle-tier, which would be a set of web services, is made available via the WAN; but the database server is directly available to the middle-tier.

Comment: @neoistheone Alright. I decided to use web services. They work like a dream. Thank you very much.

Comment: @chosenOneThabs, I'm glad we could be of assistance!